# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException:

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

Here I am opening a Chrome browser and trying to send input string to the WebElement search text box:

```
// search for a text in Google
WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver1,30);
WebElement textBox = wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class = 'gsfi']")));
```

Error Observed for Chrome

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state
(Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
System info: host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '192.168.1.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f), userDataDir=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir15624_26281}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=62.0.3202.94, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: d4178e5e05d8efc8800ec1e1ceb1f63a
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:100)
    at packageFF.browserAutomation.main(browserAutomation.java:76)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're searching for input elements that have the class '`gsfi`'. A quick search through the Google homepage html returns three input elements that have this class, two of them are hidden. The field that you need to send text to has an id, so why not use the id?

```
// The input element you need
<input class="gsfi" id="lst-ib" .../>

// Locate element by id
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver1, 30);
WebElement textBox = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("list-ib")));
```

Answer (score 0):

`By.xpath("//input[@class = 'gsfi']")` is not found through xpath because it is not opened successfully. You can set sleep time also.

And if possible, you can use id or class instead of xpath.